# OperationhandlerFunc second parameter becomes interface{} instead of *models.Model

Tags: go-swagger

I'm trying to add authentication to my api following the go-swagger tutorial: https://goswagger.io/tutorial/composed-auth/

But my generated code becomes:

```
type GetAuthenticatedUserHandlerFunc func(GetAuthenticatedUserParams, interface{}) middleware.Responder
```

While in the example it is:

```
type AddOrderHandlerFunc func(AddOrderParams, *models.Principal) middleware.Responder
```

I can't seem to find how to make the second parameter a reference to model. I have a model called `user` defined. If i try to do:

```
func GetAuthenticatedUserHandlerFunc(params auth.GetAuthenticatedUserParams, user *models.User) middleware.Responder
```

I get this error:

```
cannot convert handlers.GetAuthenticatedUserHandlerFunc (type func(auth.GetAuthenticatedUserParams, *models.User) "github.com/wunari/easypoll-backend/vendor/github.com/go-openapi/runtime/middleware".Responder) to type auth.GetAuthenticatedUserHandlerFunc
```

How can i make the generated code use the user model?

My swagger.yml: https://github.com/wunari/easypoll-backend/blob/master/docs/swagger.yml

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was missing the -P (--principal) flag when generating with go-swagger cli.

Example:

```
swagger generate server -t docs -f ./docs/swagger.yml --exclude-main -A easypoll --principal models.User
```